# What is the origin of the phrase "the kindness of strangers"

Tags: phrase-origin

Blanche Dubois uses the phrase (in "Street Car Named Desire") but, since she is using it ironically (or perhaps deluding herself), is there an older source?   A quick search gives lots of books, films, bands, and other uses of the phrase but I've found nothing earlier than Dubois (1947).

It sounds vaguely religious?  Just a euphemism?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked into [these data](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kindness+of+strangers&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)?

Comment: Just be aware that in _Streetcar_ [this phrase doesn't mean what it says on the tin](https://www.sparknotes.com/lit/streetcar/quotes/page/5/).

Comment: There are [*hundreds*, if not *thousands*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+kindness+of+strangers%22&biw=1367&bih=657&sxsrf=ALiCzsZOhxXuGCrai_5DS2y7zo-SwCksXQ%3A1672684255839&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1600%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1940&tbm=bks) of pre-WW2 written instances of ***the kindness of strangers***. It's just ordinary English with a transparent meaning (or a "transparently ironic" meaning in *Streetcar*, but that's not a common usage) - there's no need to look for an "original" instance.

Comment: tchrist - I forgotten about ngram - I wonder why it built so rapidly from 1980?
FumbleFingers - sometimes the ordinary isn't.